# AutoML Natural Language Node.js API call giving a "bad base64 decode" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl

I'm using Google's AutoML Natural Language API for Node.js. Everything works great, except for a particular service account and user (a student of mine). She gets the following error:

> Auth error:Error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
>   { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
>       at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
>       at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/ubuntu/workspace/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
>       at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/ubuntu/workspace/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
>       at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/ubuntu/workspace/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
>       at callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
>     code: 14,
>     metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
>     details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode' }

The code that produces this error is:

```
const automl = require('@google-cloud/automl')
const client = new automl.v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient({keyFilename: 'key_file.json'})
const formattedName = client.modelPath('<project-id>', 'us-central1', '<model-id>')
const payload = {
    textSnippet: {
        content: 'Recognize this text',
        mimeType: 'text/plain'
    }
}
const request = {
  name: formattedName,
  payload,
}
client.predict(request)
  .then(responses => console.log(responses[0].payload[0]))
  .catch(console.error(err))
```

If I change *project-id*, *model-id*, and *key-file.json* to my own, then this works perfect. Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Sounds like one of her three inputs are incorrect or malformed.

Comment: I've checked and they all look good. Her *model-id* is copy-pasted from the same place I found my model id. Her *project-id* is correct and her key file looks exactly like mine except, of course, the project id, private key, etc data is a little different.

Comment: May be indentation error? The private key should always with format like `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----{\n{someChar}*64\n}*{some constant}-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`. But I don't think google make such mistake for generating this key....

Comment: @MatrixTai I’ve compared JSON key files with mine, all _looks_ good...